# Why do some C math expressions require constants to be explicitly marked as floats?

Tags: objective-c, c, math

So I just found this bug in my code and I am wondering what rules I'm not understanding.

I have a `float` variable logDiff, that currently contains a very small number. I want to see if it's bigger than a constant expression (80% of a 12th). I read years ago in *Code Complete* to just leave calculated constants in their simplest form for readability, and the compiler (XCode 4.6.3) will inline them anyway. So I have,

```
            if ( logDiff > 1/12 * .8 ) {
```

I'm assuming the .8 and the fraction all evaluates to the correct number. Looks legit:

```
(lldb) expr (float) 1/12 * .8
(double) $1 = 0.0666666686534882
(lldb) expr logDiff
(float) $2 = 0.000328541
```

But it always *wrongly* evaluates to true. Even when I mess with enclosing parens and stuff.

```
(lldb) expr logDiff > 1/12 * .8
(bool) $4 = true
(lldb) expr logDiff > (1/12 * .8)
(bool) $5 = true
(lldb) expr logDiff > (float)(1/12 * .8)
(bool) $6 = true
```

I found I have to explicitly spell at least one of them as floats to get the correct result,

```
(lldb) expr logDiff > (1.f/12.f * .8f)
(bool) $7 = false
(lldb) expr logDiff > (1/12.f * .8)
(bool) $8 = false
(lldb) expr logDiff > (1./12 * .8f)
(bool) $11 = false
(lldb) expr logDiff > (1./12 * .8)
(bool) $12 = false
```

but I recently read [a popular style guide](https://github.com/github/objective-c-conventions#literals) explicitly eschew these fancier numeric literals, apparently according to my assumption that the compiler would be smarter than me and Do What I Mean.

Should I always spell my numeric constants like `1.f` if they might need to be a float? Sounds superstitious. Help me understand why and when it's necessary?

Comment: This just seems like operator precedence issue. In your testing you wrote `expr (float) 1/12 * .8` where the typecast occurs before the integer division. In your later testing you have `expr logDiff > (float)(1/12 * .8)` where the typecast happens after the integer division has turned `1/12 => 0`.

Comment: "Should I always spell my numeric constants like 1.f if they might need to be a float? Sounds superstitious.". No, sounds like good programming practice: use the intended type rather than a type that you don't want. You want float not int. Then why use int literals? Never use integer literals when point floating point arithmetic and all your problems will go away. There is never a case in C where it makes sense to type `1/12` in the source code, regardless of possible typecasts. Instead, you should write `1.0f / 12.0f`.

Comment: It's awesome that the "popular styleguide" uses the word "shit" in example variables. :)

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the excellent answers and comments. You have enlightened me and I wish I could accept all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C `int/int` gives an `int`. If you don't explicitly tell the compiler to convert at least one to a float, it will do the division and round down to the nearest int (in this case 0).

I note that the linked style guide actually says *Avoid making numbers a specific type unless necessary*. In this case it is needed as what you want is for the compiler to do some type conversions

Answer (score 4):

The expression `1/12` is an *integer* division. That means that the result will be truncated as zero.

When you do `(float) 1/12` you cast the one as a float, and the whole expression becomes a floating point expression.

Comment: ahah, I see, but in my lldb line I said `(float)(1/12)`, casting the whole parenthesized expression which already resolved integerly to (0).

Answer (score 1):

An expression such as `1 / 4` is treated as integer division and hence has no decimal precision. In this specific case, the result will be `0`. You can think of this as `int / int` implies `int`.

> Should I always spell my numeric constants like 1.f if they might need to be a float? Sounds superstitious. Help me understand why and when it's necessary?

It's not superstitious, you are telling the compiler that these are *type* literals (floats as an example) and the compiler will treat all operations on them as such.

Moreover, you could cast an expression. Consider the following:

```
float result = ( float ) 1 / 4;
```

... I am casting `1` to be a float and hence the result of `float / int` will be `float`. See datatype operation precedence (or promotion).

Comment: But see in that case the lvalue is a float so I'm used to thinking the compiler will get it right even without the explicit cast.

Comment: @Nathan, :). I am glad you were able to understand what is going on with the aid of our answers, you only needed a small push.

Comment: Oh no! You're right, I never noticed these subtleties.

`log2diff = 1` yields **(float) 1**. 
`log2diff = 1/4` yields **(float) 0**.
`log2diff = 1./4` yields the intended `(float) 0.25`

Answer (score 1):

That is simple. Per default, a numeric value is interpredted as an `int`.
There are math expresssions where that does not matter too much. But in case of divisions it can drive you crazy. `(int) 1 / (int) 12` is not  `(float) 0.08333` but `(int) 0`. 
`1/12.0` would evaluate to `(float) 0.83333`.

Side note: When you go for float where you used int before there is one more trap waiting for you. That is when ever you compare values for equality.

```
float f = 12/12.0f; 
if (f = 1) ... // this may not work out. Never expect a float to be of a specific value. They can vary slightly.
```

Better is:

```
if (abs(f - 1) < 0.0001) ... // this way yoru comparison is fuzzy enough for the variances that float values may come with.
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of those issues from elsewhere. Also `if (f=1)` is always a terrible idea but luckily modern IDEs will catch it :D